# A fully documented Sanhedrin trial to understand the process?

Tags: beit-din-court, criminal-procedure

The Talmudic examples of Sanhedrin executions are numerous, but none brings a full documentary of the process, only the fact that someone was executed. That raises a lot of questions about the exact procedure - like where do the witnesses go first, is there a secretariat? Is there a physical file and where it's kept? Who's exactly prosecuting - who represents the "state"? And many more.

The Talmud (that was written long after the Sanhedrin of נפשות was dismissed) deals only with theoretical Halachic questions, that are hard to reconcile in a consistent process.

Is there a source (maybe external) for a fully documented Sanhedrin trial from the beginning to the end?

Comment: From what I understand (based on an article from the TABC Kol Torah publication), historically, Batei Din never really recorded their sessions like current courts do, as there was no particular need to (i.e. there is no 'appeals' process that they need to submit their opinions to, there is no setting of 'precedent'). Based on that, you're not likely to find a complete actual court proceeding from anything older than several years (not even taking into account the lack of historical records from ancient times).

Comment: (cont') That's not to say the process isn't documented: Shulchan Aruch details the complete process of court proceedings; you just aren't likely to find a specific historical example. But I''ve been surprised before by what people find, so if someone else has a historical example, I'd be fascinated to see it.

Comment: It doesn't really seem to me like they would require a prosecutor since the decision doesn't seem to have anything to do with persuasion. It's all about witness testimony.

Comment: What Shu"A, I thought it does not deal with Sanhedrin as it's not relevant today? *details the complete process of court proceedings*, do you mean דיני ממונות?

Comment: @Daniel so who represents the "state" - the Jewish nation, the KB"H?

Comment: Would a (sourced) fictionalised account interest you (not that I have one), or are you only looking for historical records?

Comment: @magicker72 I'm fine with a detailed simulation. Simply all the details I know do not make sense as a whole.

Comment: @AlBerko What do you mean by "the state"? My understanding of _halachic_ trials is that they aren't structured at all like modern trials where there's a prosecutor and a defense attorney. There's no complex argumentation. Just a bunch of witnesses come in and say what they saw, and then the judges cross-examine them to confirm whether they're telling the truth.

Comment: And that's true whether the witnesses are coming to support the "defense" or the "prosecution"

Comment: On a macro level, [Louis Jacobs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Jacobs) remarked: "It would be an extraordinarily rash scholar, today, who would be ready to pronounce with confidence on, say, the actual nature and workings of the Sanhedrin in Temple times." (A Tree Of Life, 1984 p. 24)

Comment: @AlBerko It is described pretty vividly in Sanhedrin 4

Answer (score 3):

While not an actual trial, the Mishnayoth in Sanhedrin starting at [Chapter 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.3?lang=bi) describe precisely how various trials are run.

Starting with how to choose the judges for a small 3-man Bet Din to how the 72-man Sanhedrin functions.

Then we have details about the cross-examination, how to document who-said-what and how and when the final vote is taken.

Finally, we have the various death-sentence scenarios including potential retrials.

Comment: I am aware of that, however, I can't consolidate all my knowledge into a consistent picture. How do they check who the deceased is? How are the witnesses checked for their Kashrut?  What rights does the convict have? Who's in charge to defend him? And many more. It appears that the all the Mishnayos are discussed theoretically (well they are, as nobody from the Tanoyiom or Amoroyim actually participated in one), with no documented existing processes available.

Comment: @AlBerko - there's no reason to assume the earlier Tanoim weren't part of the Sanhedrin. (Each of the very early ones - the Zugoth - was actually the Av Bet Din)

Comment: True, Sanhedrin held long after the destruction, I meant participated in a capital trial. If you're familiar with Kidush Hachodesh Beis Din discussions (in Rosh Hashone) you can have an idea what mess it was  - there was no agreement even on such a simple thing as declaring new moon, and what inconsistencies they are talking about, so judging a capital crime - they wouldn't even agree on a procedure. Wow I think it is a good question on its own!

Comment: @AlBerko The 72-person Sanhedrin lost its ability to judge capital cases 40 years before the destruction. It continued to function in Yavneh for long after the destruction. The Tannaic period began not too long after the *construction* of the Temple - the division between Tannaim and Anshei Kinesses HaGedolah was the cessation of prophecy, not the destruction. The destruction took place during the days of R’ Akiva, three generations before R’ Yehudah HaNasi. So the Sanhedrin lasted through most of the Tannaic period, which was 11 generations if you count the pairs.

Comment: @DonielF I'm confused - was I right saying that the none of the Tannoyim and Amoroyim of the Gemmorah participated in any Sanhedrin judging a capital crime?

Comment: No, no you were not. We can start with Shimon Ben Shetach, a very early Tanna, who judged several capital cases (and executed several, but those were extralegal).

Comment: @DonielF Extralegal, exactly, I'd like to find one clear legal case. It seems that all cases were somehow not truly Halachic, but based on their authority instead.  Also, Shimon Ben Shetach is mentioned but he's not a "Tannah of the Gemmorah", like King David.

Comment: No, the case was an actual witch (several, IIRC). They just couldn’t kill her according to the law. Shimon Ben Shetach was absolutely a Tanna. King David was not even close to being a Tanna.

Comment: @DonielF Fascinating that the Sanhedrin didn't judge *dinei nefashos* 40 years before the destruction- do you possibly have the *mekor* for that?

Comment: @alicht See RH 31a